# Extracting individual frames from an image

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7, numpy

I am currently new to python and I want to extract the R, G and B frame separately from an image.

For instance, the variable which stores my image is img

What I want to know;

how do I make `Rimg = img (:,:,1)`
`Gimg = img (:,:,2)`
`Bimg = img (:,:,3)`
Ofcource, these are MATlab pseudo codes and Rimg, Gimg and Bimg are just variables.

Comment: They're called color channels. You might find that easier to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy style :

```
Bimg = img[:,:,0]
Gimg = img[:,:,1]
Rimg = img[:,:,2]
```

OpenCV style :

```
B,G,R = cv2.split(img)
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing it in numpy stype :) By the way, excellent blogs, helped me a lot in getting around python!

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct, but this is a common enough operation that a one-liner can be idiomatic:

```
# Let `im` be a numpy array
r,g,b = im.transpose((2,0,1))
```

The `transpose` operator changes the axes around so that the first axis become the channel axis. Then you can use standard Python multiple assignment to assign to `r`,`g`, and `b`.

Comment: ah this way is a nice and an efficient way to go about it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you load your data as a [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) [`ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) using any one of many image libraries in Python ([OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/), [Mahotas](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mahotas), [scikits.image](http://scikit-image.org/), [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)), then basically the exact same syntax as Matlab will work:

```
Rimg = img[:,:,0] 
Gimg = img[:,:,1] 
Bimg = img[:,:,2]
```